# How do I alter just the framerate of a VP9 webm without affecting anything else?

Tags: video, framerate

- I wish to change just the framerate of a VP9 encoded webm file.
- The source file has a framerate of 1000 FPS, and I'd like to change it to 30 FPS, without affecting the video/audio in any other way.
- I'm a completely blank slate at video encoding/editing. No prior experience/knowledge
- Google had no answers for me

Questions:

1. Is there a way to do it? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04
2. Will lowering the framerate mean lowered CPU usage?

Answer (score 1):

This has come up before for other codecs / containers.

[This DOESN'T](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video) work in ffmpeg without transcoding, since ffmpeg unfortunately isn't set up for messing with timestamps on non-decoded frames.

I *think* you should be able to do it with this (untested):
`mkvmerge --default-duration 0:30fps  in.webm -o out.webm`

Where `0` is the track-id of the video track.  Check the man page for mkvmerge for more details.  Note that it says that `--fix-bitstream-timing-information` is only implemented for h.264 currently, so your output will have a vp9 stream that probably still says it's 1000 fps, but the container will have frame timestamps at 30fps.  Players almost always use container presentation-timestamps, though.

If there is audio with the video, I assume it's the right length for the video being 30fps?  Otherwise that's a big stretch needed...

Comment: I did not know that it was possible for a video's metadata to show 1000 fps but be 30 fps instead. Maybe that's what is happening in my source video? Is there a way to check?

Comment: Well some video codecs can store an FPS in the bitstream, separate from the timestamps in the container.  A quick google found this link that might help explain why there are multiple layers of things.  http://www.pitivi.org/manual/codecscontainers.html.  edit: and here's a link that looks better, in more detail.  https://library.rice.edu/services/dmc/guides/video/VideoFormatsGuide.pdf

Comment: There must be a good FAQ for stuff like this somewhere?  Anyone have a link that makes a good boilerplate answer to give to confused beginners?

Comment: To answer your question: you could say that the ACTUAL fps of your video was the real time interval between the frames that the camera recorded.  If you play it back at a different FPS, time in the displayed video will be sped up or slowed down.

Comment: oh, and also, how did you determine it was 1000fps?  mplayer shows 1000fps for some variable-frame-rate files, just as a placeholder.  Unless you did something weird, or there's a bug in something you used (certainly possible since VP9 is still new), it's highly unlikely you really have a video that will play at 1000fps.

Comment: also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/370692/how-to-change-the-framerate-of-a-video-without-reencoding